# Passport JWt Authetication for hyperledger composer API

Tags: mongodb, hyperledger-composer, passport-jwt

[call back for access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnp6t.jpg)I am searching for a solution to implement passport jwt authetication strategy for hyperledger composer REST API. I have followed this link for setting up passport authetication https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn.

Generating hyperledger composer API,creating composer rest server docker container , API's are protected everything seems working except the access token generation , how to retrieve that token.

Also i created another nodejs application with passport jwt, mongodb with few users added. I was able to succesfully generate token from that application and protect any express routes using that token.

But my struggling point is how to generate token for the composer rest server API

As explained in many articles i have created custom jwt , environment varibales as follows

### custom jwt

```
const passportJwt = require('passport-jwt');
const util = require('util');

function CustomJwtStrategy(options, verify) {
  options.jwtFromRequest = passportJwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  passportJwt.Strategy.call(this, options, verify);
}

util.inherits(CustomJwtStrategy, passportJwt.Strategy);

module.exports = {
  Strategy: CustomJwtStrategy
};
```

### Environment variables

```
COMPOSER_CARD=admin@tutorial-network
COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=never
COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=true
COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=true
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "jwt": {
    "provider": "jwt",
    "module": "/home/composer/node_modules/custom-jwt.js",
    "secretOrKey": "admin",
    "authScheme": "saml",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect":"/"
    }
}'
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
  "db": {
    "name": "auth",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "host": "mongo"
  }
}'
```

[composer rest server logs on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiH7w.jpg)

Now from where should i generate the token, how to retrive that token so that i can capture and pass it in headers for the hyperledger composer business API's.

Please help with details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the token generated by node js. One thing you need to take care is you have to use same here  `"secretOrKey": "admin"` customkey with  which you are generating token in node js

Make request as shown in an image as you are using `options.jwtFromRequest =passportJwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();` . It will store the access_token in cookie. Then you can retrieve it from cookie for further use.

[image]

Comment: Hi @honey shah, Thanks for the response. I am using the same secretOrKey which i am using in passport strategy token generation app. I have generated jwt token and tried calling http://localhost:3000/auth/jwt/callback?token= < jwt token>, but i am getting 200 response with html source as below

Comment: Hi @honey shah, Thanks for the response. I am using the same secretOrKey which i am using in passport strategy token generation app. I have generated jwt token and tried calling http://localhost:3000/auth/jwt/callback?token= < jwt token>, but i am getting 200 response with html source. do not see access token. Also one more point i would like to mention is i am using opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt'); in the nodejs application which generates token, but in custome jwt file we mentioned as passportJwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();. Will it be a issue

Comment: Yes @honey shah

Comment: Try to run it native postman instead of chrome extension and then see.

Comment: I did try now, it is same result, HTML source response with 200 status code

Comment: This may be due to some problem in your jwt token. Can you show the screenshot of postman (request and response)?

Comment: Hi, I am unable to attach the screenshot , site says not enough points to embed the images.

Comment: Hi Honey shah, please click on the link " call back for access token " for postman request and response at the beginning of my question. Stackoverflow  has linked the image due to my account privilages. Thanks

Comment: Hi Honey Shah, if u have got chance to look into the link i mentioned, please help if you got any idea on error.

Comment: @AShokEdiga I have edited the answer. You can look into this once.

Comment: Thanks Shah for response. I tried in the same way in native postman but no luck